# Backing up Docker Images from Crontab

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I was looking for a simple way to backup my existing docker instances into the corresponding tar archives, and I wrote the following script. I do understand that Docker instances should simply be destroyed and re-created from Dockerfile(s). However, I have users who modify running instances without keeping track of the steps taken. I wanted to support their efforts by backing up their work. Any suggestions on how to improve the strategy? Is there a clear way to export running instances into Dockerfile(s)?

---

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGETAG=$(date +"%Y")
TARDATE=$(date +"%m%Y")
SAVEDIR=/data/.docker_bak

for IMAGENAME in $(docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'); 
do
   docker rmi ${IMAGENAME}:${IMAGETAG}
   docker stop ${IMAGENAME}
   sleep 1
   docker commit ${IMAGENAME} ${IMAGENAME}:${IMAGETAG}
   sleep 1
   docker start ${IMAGENAME}
   docker save -o ${SAVEDIR}/${IMAGENAME}_${TARDATE}.tar ${IMAGENAME}:${IMAGETAG}
done
```

Comment: This is absolutely not the way to manage docker infrastructure. Images should be deployable build artifacts that are only modified at build time.

Comment: You said they modify running instances, do they modify images as well ?

Comment: A few concerns: `docker rmi` won't succeed in removing the underlying image of a running container; it is unneeded stopping a container to trigger `docker commit` on it; and finally as pointed out by @jordanm this workflow sounds non-idiomatic! see e.g. this reference which definitely advises against using `docker commit` (point 5): https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/24/10-things-to-avoid-in-docker-containers/